# Excel spreadsheet imported as a list into SharePoint 2010, is creating extra HTML tags

Tags: 2010, list, import, spreadsheet

I have several lists that I imported into a publishing site on SharePoint 2010.  It appears that the import process created lists with problems.  All the fields ended up with extra html tags (i.e. color, and a referance to an external class) and those tags interfere with the CSS.

Has anyone encountered this?  Does anyone have a solution